# Save current Workbook as separate Excel Workbook via dialog box

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I am trying to make a button that would show a save as dialog box and upon saving would save the current workbook as separate Excel Workbook that I enter a filename and location for.

What I have so far code wise is:

```
Private Sub Save_Button_Click()

Application.GetSaveAsFilename InitialFileName:="S0000.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Could someone, please, share a code for this operation?

Comment: Do you want to save the workbook as `xlsx` or `xlsm`?

Comment: [Application.GetSaveAsFilename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133143);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: [More Links](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Application.GetSaveAsFilename+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib5P-K5vrvAhWPbSsKHQxQB1MQrQIoBHoECBcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=937)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Save_Button_Click()
    dim fName as variant

    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:="S0000.xlsx", _
        FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault

End Sub
```

This is adapted from the example at [Duplicate your workbook in seconds](https://www.excelquicker.com/tips/recent-tips/duplicate-your-workbook-in-seconds/).

It saves the *active* workbook (i.e. the one currently open in the foreground of Excel). This may or may not be the workbook containing the code.

If you want to instead make sure the workbook containing this code is the one saved, change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`.

To trap for a filename not being provided by the user (after they delete your default one), you could add a conditional statement to check, for example like this:

```
Private Sub Save_Button_Click()
    dim fName as variant

    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:="S0000.xlsx", _
        FileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If fName <> False Then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But what is that fName? That whole line appears red for me

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` set? If you do, add a line above `Do` that reads `Dim fName$` (edited answer accordingly)

Comment: It does open a dialog box and format is "All Files" which is incorrect. It doesn't even let you change the format to save the file as

Comment: Answer updated to include xlsx file format instead of "all files" (unspecified)

Comment: Nope, this seems incorrect, I can't even cancel saving and the whole code is red

Comment: Thanks, this almost works but gives type mismatch after saving on line     Loop Until fName <> False

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231053/discussion-between-ed2-and-eduards).

Comment: Updated example should now work

Comment: 6 EDITS! :D Remove the "( )" from Msgbox. Also change `Dim fName$` as `Dim fName As Variant`. Did you not test your code before posting? :)

Comment: Why remove `()`? Curious. Removed `Dim` (so, 7?) as it is unnecessary unless the OP has `Option Explicit` in the module. Code is tested but my context and OPs may differ.

Comment: Now it is better :) But still `MsgBox "You did not provide a filename. File not saved.", vbExclamation, "File save error"` is better than `mAns = MsgBox("You did not provide a filename. File not saved.", vbExclamation, "File save error")`

Comment: Ok, updated accordingly regarding not trapping message box result. Sorry made previous edit before seeing suggested edit. Still, declaring the variable is 'just in case' the OP has `Option Explicit`; I would not have removed that if the question included OE or a requirement to declare. It is reinstated in any event, for posterity in application to different circumstances ahead of the simplicity of omitting the (possibly unnecessary) declarations. Thanks for steering!

Comment: I posted it in the discussion